# How to filter own output in perl6?

Tags: raku

I want to filter own output without writing separate program for that. There is perl5 solution that may be adapted. Is there something better that can be done like that new language supports?

```
head(100);
while (<>) {
  print;
} 

sub head {
 my $lines = shift || 20;
 return if $pid = open(STDOUT, "|-");
 die "cannot fork: $!" unless defined $pid;
 while (<STDIN>) {
    print;
    last unless --$lines ;
 } 
 exit;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28702850/1077672?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@raiph comment helped me a lot

It is possible to substitute OUT class with anything needed. This preserves laziness that  [IO::Capture::Simple](https://github.com/sergot/IO-Capture-Simple/) seem not to have yet.

This example does very simple duplicated lines cut out

```
my $undecorated_out = $*OUT;
my $decorated_out = class {
    my @previous="nothing";
    method print(*@args) {
        my @toprint;
        if @args[0] eq @previous[0] {
            @toprint = ("...\n")
        }else{
            @toprint = @args;
        }
        $undecorated_out.print(@toprint) ;
        @previous = @args unless @args[0] eq "\n";
    }
    method flush {}
}
$*OUT = $decorated_out;
```