# How do I `say` and `print` into a buffer?

Tags: io, raku, rakudo

In Perl 6 the Str type is immutable, so it seems reasonable to use a mutable buffer instead of concatenating a lot of strings. Next, I like being able to use the same API regardless if my function is writing to stdout, file or to an in-memory buffer.

In Perl, I can create an in-memory file like so

```
my $var = "";
open my $fh, '>', \$var;
print $fh "asdf";
close $fh;
print $var;          # asdf
```

How do I achieve the same thing in Perl 6?

Comment: cf https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28702850/i-can-create-filehandles-to-strings-in-perl-5-how-do-i-do-it-in-perl-6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a minimal [IO::String](https://github.com/hoelzro/p6-io-string/) in the [ecosystem](http://modules.perl6.org/) backed by an array.

For a one-off solution, you could also do someting like

```
my $string;
my $handle = IO::Handle.new but role {
    method print(*@stuff) { $string ~= @stuff.join };
    method print-nl       { $string ~= "\n" }
};

$handle.say("The answer you're looking for is 42.");
dd $string;
```

Answer (score 2):

What I currently do is that I wrapped string concatenation in a class as a temporary solution.

```
class Buffer {
    has $!buf = "";
    multi method print($string) {
        $!buf ~= $string;
    }
    multi method say($string) {
        $!buf ~= $string ~ "\n";
    }
    multi method Str() {
        return $!buf;
    }
}
```

With that, I can do

```
my $buf = Buffer.new();
say $buf: "asdf";
print $buf.Str;
```